# Find interval between scucessive conjunctions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

The maths here doesn't seem to be too hard, but for some reason I can't quite figure out what to do:

Consider two planets orbiting a star in circular orbits with periods $T_1$ and $T_2$. What is the time interval between successive conjunctions wrt to the star (ie the times of zero angular separation)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period#Synodic_period

Comment: Related question on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18380/16685